# Salesforce object field mapping

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce and I have issue if someone can please help me.

So, there is Account object which is the standard object. There are many fields in Account object. One of them is the Address field. How would I know what jobs is populating this address field. I checked the bulk Api load jobs and didn't find anything that would tell me where this address field value is coming from.

Could some one please guide me in right direction ?

Tried looking to bulk api load jobs and while I found some of the account fields updated by one of the bulk api load jobs, I didn't find which integration updates the address.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put "field history tracking" on the address fields (if history isn't tracked already), wait a bit and it should capture the changes (who, when, which field, old value, new value). You'll have ye user and time, could correlate that with user's login history to decide if it was human doing stuff via browser / mobile app or more like an application. Maybe even you'd recognise the login IP.

Without tracking... You kinda could achieve similar thing looking at accounts's last modified dat and last modified by. If it's unlikely human users make any changes over weekend and yet accounts get updated...

There are few more tricks like event monitoring if you truly can't figure it out but fetching the event logs is bit involved

Try to switch the the UI to "Classic" and there should be a special report about API usage last 7 days. Not perfect, won't tell you what was modified but at least you'll have the usernames. You can even enable debug logging on a particular user you suspect, for up to 24h